# How can I trigger Enter on keypress because the event.code==="13" is not working Vs code say it is depreciated?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am making a todo list for practice JavaScript and todo is working but when I press the button by mouse it works and when I press the enter key from keyboard it dose not work. I tried to use **event.key** or event.keyCode but VS code say it is depreciated.

I try **KeyboardEvent = "Enter"**and** event.code ===13** or related commands but it doesn't work.

Comment: `event.keyCode === 13` It should be a number, not a string. Or you can use `event.key === "Enter"`

Comment: I know it will work but  event is depreciated

Comment: `event.key === 'Enter'` Did you try this?

Comment: [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated. [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) is not deprecated.

Comment: Areyou sure you want event.code rather than event.key? See the difference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent